# NOT condition in PLSQL

Tags: plsql

I am using following two conditions and they are returning different results. Can i know what I am missing

- AND NOT (count1who = pv_user OR count2who = pv_user)
- AND (count1who <> pv_user OR count2who <> pv_user)

Comment: Please show us your complete stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

According to the De Morgan's laws, when a disjunction is negated, all operands need to be negated **and** the operator has to change from an `OR` to an `AND` (an vice versa for negating a conjunction). You missed the latter part.

So

```
NOT (count1who = pv_user OR count2who = pv_user)
```

is equivalent to

```
(count1who <> pv_user AND count2who <> pv_user)
```